# Raspberry pi 3- windows 10 iot core sd card size reduced

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I have Kingston SD card (16GB Class 10 , 45MB/s). I installed Windows 10 IoT Core. I noticed that sd card size is reduced to 63.7MB.

Is it normal or it is problem with card or some other issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normal.  It has to do with how the SD card is provisioned.

The card size isn't actually reduced, anyway.  It is just partitioned into a few filesystems that get mounted as the operating system boots up.

Answer (score -1):

yes it is normal.

don't worry it total size is 16 GB.

the size is occupy by OS.

Comment: if you have also dout then install partition guru software and quick format of your memory card.

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.